# In python program need to make a simple calculator to respond based on user's input

Tags: python, calculator

The following is what I have done: Idea is to be able to calculate the result from 2 numbers depending whether the user wanted to add them, subtract, divide or multiply.

```
    print 'Welcome to my calculator program'
    Equation = raw_input('You want to add, subtract, divide or multiply? '
    firstno = raw_input ('Please enter first number ')
    secondno = raw_input('Please enter second number ')
    F1 = int(firstno)
    F2 = int(secondno)
    F3 = F1 + F2
    print F1, '+' ,F2, '=' ,F3
```

I am not actually responding to the user's input but rather assuming he would key in add. How can I code it such that it will react differently if the user want to subtract instead of add and so on? Tnks for help.

Comment: You're going to need [if statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements). Also it's a good idea to read the whole tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dictionary dispatch and some of the functions in the `operator` module as a base.

```
import operator as op

operations = {
    'add': {'func': op.add, 'char': '+'},
    'minus': {'func': op.sub, 'char': '-'}
}
```

Then lookup the keyword and apply the function and display the equation:

```
print F1, operations[Equation]['char'], F2, '=', operations[Equation]['func'](F1, F2)
```

Comment: I really love the `operator` module. It always turns out handy.

Answer (score 0):

def start():

```
#main input variable to get a sign to do
calculator = input('What would you like to calculate? (x, /, +, -): ')
#gets 2 #'s to multiply, add, subtract, or divide 
if (calculator) == ('+'):
    add = input('what is the frist number would you like to add? ')
    addi = input('what is the second number would you like to add? ')
elif (calculator) ==('-'):
    sub = input('what is the first number would you like to subtract? ')
    subt = input('what is the second number you would like to subtract? ')
elif (calculator) == ('/'):
    div = input('what is the first number would you like to divide? ')
    divi = input('what is the second number would you like to divide? ')
elif (calculator) == ('x'):
    mult = input('what is the first number would you like to multiply? ')
    multi = input('what is the second number would you like to multiply? ')

#failsafe if done incorrect
elif (calculator) != ('x', '/', '-', '+'):
    print('try again')
    return


#adds 2 inputted #'s
if calculator == '+' :
    sumAdd = float (add) + float (addi)
    print(sumAdd)
#multiplies the 2 inputted #'s
elif calculator == 'x' :
    sumMul =  float (mult) * float (multi)
    print(sumMul)
#divides the 2 inputted #'s
elif calculator == '/' :
    sumDiv = float (div) / float (divi)
    print(sumDiv)
#subtracting the 2 inputted #'s
elif calculator == '-' :
    sumSub = float (sub) - float (subt)
    print(sumSub)

#returns to top of code to do another setup


return
```

start()

There is my calcuator
Remember inputs on your +, -, *, / before jumping into numbers